# ResizeObserver one vs multiple performance

Tags: javascript

The [ResizeObserver](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver) has an [observe()](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/#dom-resizeobserver-observe) method and an [unobserve()](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver/#dom-resizeobserver-unobserve) method. This seems to encourage having one [ResizeObserver](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver) instance and observing and unobserving different elements as needed with logic in the callback to handle each entity. Is there any performance implications of doing this vs instantiating multiple [ResizeObserver](https://wicg.github.io/ResizeObserver)s for observing different elements or groups of elements?

Comment: the unobserve method isn't encouraging reuse of a resize observer. It's a neccesity to allow proper garbage collection of listeners and elements

Comment: Like the `MutationObserver`, `disconnect()` can be used for garbage collection.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like reusing (one) the ResizeObserver is preferred and more preformant:

https://github.com/WICG/ResizeObserver/issues/59#issuecomment-408098151
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/z6ienONUb5A/F5-VcUZtBAAJ