# How to utilize ResizeObserver for multiple behaviors

Tags: javascript, performance, observers

It seems that [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) is best used when you have one instance managing the behaviors of many elements (as pointed out in [one of the sources](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/z6ienONUb5A/m/F5-VcUZtBAAJ) from ["ResizeObserver one vs multiple performance"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528940/resizeobserver-one-vs-multiple-performance)):

> Observe size of 126 divs during a 2 second animation of width/height.
>
> 1. All elements are observed by a single ResizeObserver.
>
>    Total observer time: 69ms
> 2. Each element is observed by separate ResizeObserver.
>
>    Total observer time: 585ms

However, as far as I can tell you can only really specify a single behavior for an instance of `ResizeObserver`, which then gets run for any elements that it's observing. **How should I observe multiple elements with different behaviors?** From what I can see, I can either:

- Use a single instance of `ResizeObserver` and figure out at runtime what behavior should be used for a given element (which seems needlessly complex, and I don't know how reliable comparing element references would be in production), or
- Use multiple instances of `ResizeObserver`, which would make behavior simpler but theoretically reduce performance.

Alternatively, are the performance losses for using multiple instances of `ResizeObserver` even something that I should be worried about at a small to medium scale?

Answer (score 1):

> …figure out at runtime what behavior should be used for a given element (which seems needlessly complex, and I don't know how reliable comparing element references would be in production)…

I don't think this needs to be particularly complicated.

You could have a collection of behaviors, each with a `predicate` function and a `handler` function. The predicate determines whether it's applicable to the given element, and the handler performs the behavior. (This might not be super performant if you've got thousands of behaviors, but I'm assuming you don't.)

Something along these lines?

```js
const behaviors = [
  {
    predicate: element => element.classList.contains('first'),
    handler: element => {
      // do stuff
    }
  },
  {
    predicate: element => element.classList.contains('second'),
    handler: element => {
      // do other stuff
    }
  },
];

const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
    for (let entry of entries) {
      // for single behavior
      behaviors.find(b => b.predicate(entry))?.handler(entry);
      
      // or every applicable behavior
      behaviors
        .filter(b => b.predicate(entry))
        .forEach(b => b.handler(entry);
    }
})
```

Comment: I like this solution better than what I had in mind (which involved matching element references and running handlers from there), however I'm still not sure that this is the kind of granularity nor workflow I want.

Comment: Fair enough. Consider that the list of behaviors wouldn't necessarily have to be all in one place like this. You could import behaviors from wherever makes sense in your app and create the complete array from there. `[ ...dogBehaviors, ...catBehaviors, ...beaverBehaviors ]` or whatever.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll play around with this and see how viable it is with my normal workflow